# C++0x emplace_back with non-copyable Items

Tags: stl, c++11

I wonder if I understood `emplace_back` correctly

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Hero {
    Hero(const string&) {}
    Hero(const char*) {}
    Hero(int) {}
    // forbid a clone:
    Hero(const Hero&) = delete;
    Hero& operator=(const Hero&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    vector<Hero> heros1 = { "Bond", "Hulk", "Tarzan" }; // ERR: copies?

    vector<Hero> heros;
    heros.emplace_back( 5 );              // ERR: copies
    heros.emplace_back( string("Bond") ); // ERR: copies
    heros.emplace_back( "Hulk" );         // ERR: copies
}
```

Thus, I am really wondering If I understood `emplace_back` incorrectly: I though it would *prevent* to make a copy of `Hero`, because it creates the Item *in-place*.

Or is it a implementation error in my g++-4.7.0?

Comment: It's no longer C++0x. It's just C++ now! `:)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define a move constructor and move-assignment operator, like this:

```
struct Hero {
    Hero(const string&) {}
    Hero(const char*) {}
    Hero(int) {}

    Hero(Hero&&) {}
    Hero& operator=(Hero&&) { return *this; }

    // forbid a clone:
    Hero(const Hero&) = delete;
    Hero& operator=(const Hero&) = delete;
};
```

This allows values of type Hero to be moved into the function.  Move is usually faster than copy.  If the type is neither copyable nor movable then you cannot use it in a `std::vector`.

Comment: It should also be noted that these will be generated for you if they were missing, which is why the code compiled and ran

Comment: this is preposterous. If you need a move constructor then the emplace is not really forwarding the **inplace** constructor any variadic arguments, you are still making a moved copy. That would make emplace_back utterly useless

Comment: @lurscher To be used in a `std::vector` at all, objects must be copyable or movable.

Answer (score 4):

It's no implementation error- you did not provide a move constructor.

Comment: You were quick! I was just typing my own answer ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Uh... I got it.

If I forbit to **copy** the `Hero`s, I must allow them to **move**, if I want to put them in containers. How silly of me.

```
struct Hero {
    Hero(const string&) {}
    Hero(const char*) {}
    Hero(int) {}
    // no clone:
    Hero(const Hero&) = delete;
    Hero& operator=(const Hero&) = delete;
    // move only:
    Hero(Hero&&) {}
    Hero& operator=(Hero&&) {}
};
```

And all examples **except for the initializer list** work.

Comment: Do note that `emplace_back` itself does *not* require the type to be movable - it does construct the item in-place as you thought. However, `std::vector` *in general* requires its element type to be either movable or copyable, otherwise it couldn't grow as needed.